# What causes this StackPanel scrolling issue?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, layout, windows-phone-8

I have a Customer Pages which contains information of customer name. This page contains a **StackPanel** and inside this StackPanel there is a **ScrollViewer** and inside the ScrollViewer there is another **StackPanel**.

I am adding number of StackPanels dynamically. Inside the StackPanel I am adding TextBlock dynamically behind, which contains text. Then add InkPresenter to show a separation.

My problem is after adding every time when I try to use the page, it doesn't scroll. In fact if I swipe up the page goes down and come back.

**XAML :**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Margin="0,-20,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
       <StackPanel Height="Auto" x:Name="pottilelist"  >
       </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>




StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
stk.Name = g.id.ToString();
stk.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(Customer_Click);

TextBlock tbx = new TextBlock();
tbx.Text = g.customername;
tbx.Name = "A" + g.id.ToString();
tbx.FontSize = 36;
tbx.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(Customer_Click);
tbx.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

stk.Children.Add(tbx);

InkPresenter ink = new InkPresenter();
ink.Height = 4;
ink.Background = Brush3;
ink.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20);

stk.Children.Add(ink);

pottilelist.Children.Add(stk);
```

In one app it worked, but in another it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. This problem occurs when there is no height for a stackpanel or scrollviewer. **Height Issue**

Comment: Mark it as the answer if it is so

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the scrol viewer around the Layout Grid (main grid) that contains all page contents. I think this should solve the problem.

As long as you are using Pivot Template , just put it after the deceleration of that pivot item around the grid and it should works !

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="PivotItem">

            <ScrollViewer>

            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#7F000000" >
```

Comment: I have a pivot, this thing is inside the pivot item. So it would not work..! any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your stackpanel is placed inside the grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In above code scrollviewer will work as expected, because of the height.
If you have set the height of the position in its visual tree, then scrollviewer might not scroll.